# Сanonical form of a quadratic form by Lagrange's method

Tags: quadratic-forms

This is just an eg. to understand how to solve it.

There is a quadratic form as below we need to bring to canonical form using Lagrange's method and find the coordinate transformation.

Then find the positive & negative indexes, rank of the quadratic form. Finnally, to investigate sign-definiteness of the quadratic form by two ways: according to it's canonical form and the criterion of Sylvester:
$4x_{1}^2+2x_{2}^2+10x_{3}^2-4x_{1}x_{2}-12x_{1}x_{3}-8x_{2}x_{3}$

Any clarification on how to do it are very welcomed.

Comment: This looks like a very specific homework question.  It seems there is an underlying  "canonical form" and a "Lagrange's method" that you likely know of, so my suggestion is that you use that method (whatever it is).

Comment: https://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Lagrange_method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Lagrange's method,](https://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Lagrange_method) as such, would give
$$ (2x-y-3z)^2 +(y-7z)^2 - 48 z^2 $$
for two positive and one negative eigenvalues.

$$ Q^T D Q = H  $$
$$\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
 -  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  & 1 & 0 \\ 
 -  \frac{ 3 }{ 2 }  &  - 7 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
4 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 &  - 48 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 &  -  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  &  -  \frac{ 3 }{ 2 }  \\ 
0 & 1 &  - 7 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
 = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
4 &  - 2 &  - 6 \\ 
 - 2 & 2 &  - 4 \\ 
 - 6 &  - 4 & 10 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$

There is a method that is the reverse of Lagrange, and done carefully gives both directions,

Algorithm discussed at http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1388421/reference-for-linear-algebra-books-that-teach-reverse-hermite-method-for-symmetr
 https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylvester%27s_law_of_inertia
$$ H = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
4 &  - 2 &  - 6 \\ 
 - 2 & 2 &  - 4 \\ 
 - 6 &  - 4 & 10 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$
$$  D_0 = H  $$
$$ E_j^T D_{j-1} E_j = D_j  $$
$$  P_{j-1} E_j = P_j  $$
$$ E_j^{-1} Q_{j-1}  = Q_j  $$
$$  P_j Q_j = Q_j P_j = I  $$
$$ P_j^T H P_j = D_j  $$
$$ Q_j^T D_j Q_j = H  $$

$$ H = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
4 &  - 2 &  - 6 \\ 
 - 2 & 2 &  - 4 \\ 
 - 6 &  - 4 & 10 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$

==============================================

$$ E_{1} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 &  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  & 0 \\ 
0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$
$$  P_{1} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 &  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  & 0 \\ 
0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
, \; \; \; Q_{1} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 &  -  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  & 0 \\ 
0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
, \; \; \; D_{1} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
4 & 0 &  - 6 \\ 
0 & 1 &  - 7 \\ 
 - 6 &  - 7 & 10 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$

==============================================

$$ E_{2} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 & 0 &  \frac{ 3 }{ 2 }  \\ 
0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$
$$  P_{2} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 &  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  &  \frac{ 3 }{ 2 }  \\ 
0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
, \; \; \; Q_{2} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 &  -  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  &  -  \frac{ 3 }{ 2 }  \\ 
0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
, \; \; \; D_{2} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
4 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 1 &  - 7 \\ 
0 &  - 7 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$

==============================================

$$ E_{3} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 1 & 7 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$
$$  P_{3} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 &  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  & 5 \\ 
0 & 1 & 7 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
, \; \; \; Q_{3} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 &  -  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  &  -  \frac{ 3 }{ 2 }  \\ 
0 & 1 &  - 7 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
, \; \; \; D_{3} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
4 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 &  - 48 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$

==============================================

$$ P^T H P = D  $$
$$\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
 \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  & 1 & 0 \\ 
5 & 7 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
4 &  - 2 &  - 6 \\ 
 - 2 & 2 &  - 4 \\ 
 - 6 &  - 4 & 10 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 &  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  & 5 \\ 
0 & 1 & 7 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
 = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
4 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 &  - 48 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$
$$ Q^T D Q = H  $$
$$\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
 -  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  & 1 & 0 \\ 
 -  \frac{ 3 }{ 2 }  &  - 7 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
4 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 &  - 48 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 &  -  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  &  -  \frac{ 3 }{ 2 }  \\ 
0 & 1 &  - 7 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
 = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
4 &  - 2 &  - 6 \\ 
 - 2 & 2 &  - 4 \\ 
 - 6 &  - 4 & 10 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$